# Разные значения слова "Свет"

Tags: омонимы

Слово "свет" означает и физическое явление (или просто отсутствие темноты), и весь мир ("белый свет"). Но почему?
Кстати, в украинском языке "Вселенная" будет "Всесвiт".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Почему" - это вопрос, обычно не имеющий ответа. Так уж получилось. )))

На самом деле исторически это действительно одно слово, означающее противоположность тьме, значение же "вселенная" приобретено уже в относительно поздний период, в восточнославянских. Возможно под действием понятия "всё, куда падает (солнечный) свет". Подобное вполне распространенное представление в самых разных культурах ("Подлунный мир", "Поднебесная", "Место под солнцем" и проч.). Не достоверно, в порядке догадки.

Comment: >значение же "вселенная" приобретено уже в относительно поздний период, в восточнославянских.

Уточню, что не только в **восточно**славянских языках. На территории бывшей Югославии *мир*, в смысле *вселенной*, это *svet* или *svit*, *svijet* (читается *свийет*), в зависимости от диалекта. 
Три разных современных произношения старославянского звука, обозначавшегося "ять", в слове **свѣтъ**.

Comment: Да? Не знал... 
Переводчик даёт на серском/хорватском "свемир"/svemir,  македонском/болгарском - вселената, словенском - vesolje. 

Хотя при обратном переводе с хорватского таки преподносит вариант "мир"...

Ну,значит, отодвинем возникновение значения на пару веков назад на момент первичного распада общеславянской общности. Тем более, что на польском тоже есть подходящее значение - świat.  
Двигать дальше - увы, не могу, в балтославянских я слаб.

Comment: >мир, в смысле вселенной

Не хотел английское слово употреблять лишний раз на русском форуме, вот и написал на скорую руку "вселенная". Всё-таки придётся прибегнуть к неслав.языку для точности. Серб.-хорв. svet/svit/svijet это как англ. world, укр. свiт. А свемир/svemir это, если не ошибаюсь, как украинское всесвiт, русс. вселенная, англ. universe.

Хорв. приставка *све-* аналогична русской *все-*. Дальше напишу кириллицей для простоты. Например, училиште -- училище, учебн. заведение, свеучилиште -- университет (по хорватски).

Comment: Nikolja, это все уже проехали. Я прекрасно Вас понял по первому комментарию - и согласился. Какая еще нужна "точность"?

PS Я через universe и искал в переводчике. И всем, кстати, рекомендую переводить на английский и с него, когда речь идет о всяких экзотических языках.

Вот если бы Вы нашли родственные соответствия в литовском или прусском...